# Is this UML diagram violating the Interface Segregation Principle?

Tags: java, design-patterns, solid-principles, interface-segregation-principle

I have created this UML diagram which applies the Template method design pattern:
[image: UML diagram]

Both concrete classes share a lot of the logic whithin the template methods createTask and completeTask, with small variations for each concrete implementation, so I went for the [Template method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). However, one of the concrete classes does not need validation, so it implements the abstract method performValidations as an empty void method.

Is this violating the Interface Segregation Principle? Or would it be OK in this situation to leave the implementation of this abstract method in the concrete class empty?

Comment: The Interface Segregation Principle is not concerned with subclasses. It's the Liskov Substitution Principle which governs inheritance. [The difference between liskov substitution principle and interface segregation principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65499896/1371329)?

Comment: I would say the issue he is encountering has nothing to do with Liskov Substitution Principle since the issue is more focused around `performValidations` having an empty implementation body rather than using derivatives of the abstract class.

Comment: Yes, my question was more around what @atish.s mentions, having an empty implementation body when implementing the Template method design pattern

Answer (score 1):

> Is this violating the Interface Segregation Principle? Or would it be OK in this situation to leave the implementation of this abstract method in the concrete class empty?

No, it is not the violation of the Interface Segregation Principle. What you have implemented is also known as `hook` in `Template Method` design pattern.

[Hook](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method) is:

> A hook is an optional step with an empty body. A template method would work even if a hook isn’t overridden.
> Usually, hooks are placed before and after crucial steps of algorithms, providing subclasses with additional
> extension points for an algorithm

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read about hooks now and what I understand is that it is declared in the abstract class and given an empty implementation, then only overridden when necessary. Should I change it to declare performValidations() in the abstract class, and only override it in the class that actually performs validations?

Comment: @JoseRoblesVillares yeah, you are right. It is necessary to move your hook to an abstract class. Having known whether you have a shared logic among derived classes, you can populate with shared logic your hook or make it empty in order to be overridden in derived classes

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of Interface Segregation Principle is that the concrete classes implementing the interface/extending an abstract class must not be forced to proivde an implementation for methods that are not relevant to them. In your case, `performValidations` is not exactly relevant for all the subclasses but yet they need to provide an implementation for it; so it is indeed violating that principle.

Without having much context on the use case of your domain, this would be my recommendation.

You could promote `performValidations` to be implemented with an empty implementation body in the abstract class itself. Whoever needs to do some validation just overrides the method `performValidations` and provide their own implementation.

Maybe a neater solution would be to have an interface `Task` as such which defines the basic idea of a `Task`.

```
public interface Task {
    /**
     * Perform steps required to create a task
     * @return true if all the steps have executed successfully.
     */
    boolean createTask();

    /**
     * Perform validations required for a task.
     * @return true if validations are successful.
     */
    default boolean validateTask(){
      return true;   
    }

    /**
     * Perform steps required to complete a task
     * @return true if all the steps have executed successfully.
     */
    boolean completeTask();
}
```

Introducing a method `executeTask` would make sense as well.

Comment: The Interface Segregation Principle is not concerned with subclasses. It's the Liskov Substitution Principle which governs inheritance.

Comment: true, I mistyped that.

Comment: The ISP is concerned with the [clients](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72148597/1371329) of an interface. It has nothing whatsoever to do with implementations or concrete classes.